# IIS - Worker threads not increasing beyond certain number even though the CPU usage is less than 40 percent

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-web-api, threadpool, iis-10

We are running a web API hosted in IIS 10 on an 8 core machine with 16 GB Memory and running Windows 10,  and throwing a load of say 100 to 200 requests per second through JMeter on the server.

Individual transactions are taking less than 500 milliseconds. When we throw the load initially, IIS threads grow up to around 150-160 mark (monitored through resource monitor and Performance monitor) and throughput increases up to 22-24 transactions per second but throughput and number of threads stop to grow beyond this point even though the CPU usage is less than 40 per cent and we have enough physical memory also available at the peak, the resource monitor does not show any choking at the network or IO level.

The web API is making calls to the Oracle database (3-4 select calls and 2-3 inserts/updates).

We fail to understand what is stopping IIS to further grow its thread pool to process more requests in parallel while all the resources including processing power, memory, network etc are available.

We have placed many performance counters as well, there is no queue build-up (that's probably because jmeter works in synchronous mode)

Also, we have tried to set the min and max threads settings through machine.config as well as ThreadPool.SetMin and Max threads APIs but no difference was observed and seems like those setting are not taking any effect.

Important to mention that we are using synchronous calls/operations (no asnch and await). Someone has advised to convert all our blocking IO calls e.g. database calls to asynchronous mode to achieve more throughput but my understanding is that if threads cant be grown beyond this level then making async calls might not help or may indeed negatively impact the throughput. Since our code size is huge, that would be a very costly activity in terms of time and effort and we dont want to invest in it till we are sure that it would really help. If someone has anything to share on these two problems, pls do share.

Below is a screenshot of the permanence monitor.

[image]

Comment: The current performance / rps is not enough for you? Do mind that the database might be the next bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you Peter, RPS on our production environment is much more than this and for that we would need to fully harness the infrastructure we have thrown at it but IIS not going beyond 20-25 TPS throughput (on a single server in a multi node environment) despite the machine having enough CPU, memory and network capacity. Lastly, database is also not overloaded so it doesn’t seem to be a bottle neck in our case either

Comment: We would want to understand A) if individual transaction is processed well within 500 milli second, every thread should be able to process 2 transactions in a second and if there are approx 50 threads we have in IIS, we should get a throughput of 100 TPS/sec, especially when we have CPU, mem and other resources available as we are not touching resource ceilings B) why IIS is not going beyond these number of threads

Comment: Windows 10 is doomed to be slower, as a desktop OS has different settings compared to Windows Server. Can you install a Windows Server to run the performance testing again?